# Downloading files from FTP

Tags: java, ftp, download, apache-commons-net

I'm trying to download files from FTP on Java using org.apache.commons.

```
try {
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(downloadedFile);
        boolean success = this.client.retrieveFile(from, os);
        System.out.println("File transfer status is "+ Boolean.toString(success));
        os.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
```

And files are downloading, but some images have error like Invalid image, another looks like that
https://www.dropbox.com/s/faozfxzag5xrk5z/Screenshot_3.png

Any ideas? Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting file type to binary, ie:

```
client.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
```

[FTPClient](http://commons.apache.org/net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html) has default settings to use `FTP.ASCII_FILE_TYPE`.